# registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener not working

Tags: android, preferences

I'm trying to update my app background color by changing the preferences but the method onSharedPreferenceChanged is never reached. The preferences are changed successfully, but I the listener doesn't work properly:

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {

private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ContactsAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    SharedPreferences mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mSettings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    SharedPreferences mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    mSettings.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_settings:
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyPreferenceActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        case R.id.action_favorite:
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    onBackPressed();
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) {

    if(key.equals("color")) {
        String color = sharedPreferences.getString("color", "3");

        int colorId = Integer.valueOf(color);

        // Alterar background

        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) ((ViewGroup) (findViewById(android.R.id.content))).getChildAt(0);

        if (colorId == 1) {
            viewGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else if (colorId == 2) {
            viewGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
        } else if (colorId == 3) {
            viewGroup.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }

    }
 }
}
```

MyPreferenceActivity:

```
public class MyPreferenceActivity extends PreferenceActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preference);

}
}
```

The method onSharedPreferenceChanged is never called,  the only way I got it to work was implement the method OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener directly inside the onResume, but sometimes it works fine, sometimes it doesn't and the method is not reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Shared preference registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener is valid only when MainActivity is in foreground else that will be unregistered in onPause.

Answer (score 2):

When you are creating a `PreferenceActivity` named `MyPreferenceActivity`, the `onPause()` of `MainActivity` is called, where the listener is getting unregistered.

One work around could be, unregister from the listener `onStop()` instead `onPause()` in `MainActivity`.

`MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    SharedPreferences mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    mSettings.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();

    SharedPreferences mSettings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getBaseContext());
    mSettings.unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

}
```

Comment: I understood my mistake, however, even if I unregister at onStop the listener still gets unregisted when I change the activity, so had to unregister in onDestroy.

Comment: `onStop()` worked for me. My answer is still closer then the accepted one!